# how to construct a mysql query that puts quotes around strings but not numbers?

Tags: php, mysql

i have use function for inserting data to my sql.
the data is

```
function mysql_insert($table, $arr){
if($arr!=''){
    $values = array_map('mysql_real_escape_string', array_values($arr));
    $keys = array_keys($arr);
    $q=('INSERT INTO `'.$table.'` (`'.implode('`,`', $keys).'`) VALUES (\''.implode('\',\'', $values).'\')');
    //$res = mysql_query($q)OR die(mysql_error());
    return $q;
}else{
    return false;
}
```

data and query is came from :

```
if($crud=='insert'){
$field= array(  'col1' => 'apel',
        'c0l2' => 'box1',
        'col3' => 200,//integer Quantity
    );
$data=mysql_insert('wh',$field);}echo json_encode($data);
```

and result is
= "INSERT INTO `wh` (`col1`,`c0l2`,`col3`) VALUES ('apel','box1','200')"
that col3 have value as string. i need that col3 as integer.
what wrong with this code?

Comment: Col 3 isn't an issue. Unlike some programming languages the apostrophes are just used as delimiters to distinguish text from variable names. As stated below the value will be converted and the INSERT should work.

Comment: Please, don't use `mysql_*` functions to write new code. They are no longer maintained and the community has begun [deprecation process](http://goo.gl/KJveJ). See the [*red box*](http://goo.gl/GPmFd)? Instead you should learn about [prepared statements](http://goo.gl/vn8zQ) and use either [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli). If you can't decide which, [this article](http://goo.gl/3gqF9) will help you. If you pick PDO, [here is good tutorial](http://goo.gl/vFWnC).

Comment: @tereško thank's for warning with mysql_* i'll try with mysqli.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is happening because the command `implode('\',\'', $values)` is telling it to turn the array `$values` into a string, with single quotes and commas between each element. If you want to not put quotes around numbers, you'll need to iterate over $values with a more specific function.

However, it doesn't actually matter. If you give MySQL a string containing a number for a numeric field, it will just convert it to a number of the appropriate type. You can leave it as-is and everything should work.

Comment: Thank's to all. yeah... i think that function (mean:mysql_*) use procedural method. i'll try to convert with mysqli. any suggestion to convert it, is welcome.

Comment: Converting to mysqli with prepared queries will also prevent this problem, since you don't need to insert quotes into your query.

Answer (score 3):

In the following code :

`implode('\',\'', $values)`

the implode is converting the array of values to a string, separating each value by `','`

and before and after the implode code, there are also quotes, which will wrap all your values with `'` make it look like all the values are strings

but like octern i don't see why the query would fail, even if you are wrapping integer values with `'` if the correct data type is selected in the database it should work fine

Answer (score 1):

If you still want to use quates around the string but not around the integer or boolean
try the php function [json_encode()](http://php.net/json_encode)
example here: http://codepad.org/Hpvzjnjc